# can I store local state in a web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm learning Web Workers in javascript, using VSCode. My worker sets up an interval during its `onmessage` event. Ideally calling start will only ever create the interval if it isn't already running.

```
onmessage = (event: MessageEvent) => {
  let interval;

  switch (event.data.command){
    case "start":
      if (!interval){
        interval = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
      }
      break;
    case "stop":
      if (interval){
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

The problem is that `interval` becomes defined within the execution of the function, so I could start multiple intervals without any of them knowing about one another.

```
const worker = new Worker("myworker.ts");
worker.postmessage({command: "start"});
worker.postmessage({command: "start"});
worker.postmessage({command: "start"});
```

If I modify the web worker code to use a global variable, like this, then according to VSCode other worker files will have access to the interval variable:

```
let interval; // Error: `interval` is already defined in `anotherWorker.ts`

onmessage = () => {
  // ...
  if (!interval){
    interval = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
  }

  // ...
  if (interval){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }
}
```

Even if each worker gets its own scope, VSCode will continue to throw errors if I reuse variable names across workers.

How can I create a local state for the worker `onmessage` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your `onmessage` handler in its own block, and declare your `interval` there. This way, other modules won't see it, but it will still persist across different message events.

```
{ // <- defines a new block
  let interval; // <- only for us, but still the same for all message events

  onmessage = () => {
    // ...
    if (!interval){
      interval = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
    }

    // ...
    if (interval){
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm working on something else for a few days but once I get to test this I'll probably accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into problems when taking an approach like @Kaiido's answer in a service worker. Browsers may restart service workers (and possibly other workers?) whenever they see fit, so you can lose state stored in variables within the worker.

In my case, I created a service worker to return all instances of an app to the login page if the user is inactive. This would sometimes fail to occur due to the worker being restarted by the browser and losing the timeout I had set.

If you want to maintain the state across service worker restarts, you should store the state in [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) and re-initialize any worker-localized state whenever it is [reactivated](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/demystifying-the-service-worker-lifecycle).

For things like timeouts and intervals which require the worker to remain alive you might strongly consider moving that functionality into the client app, where reasonable. Otherwise, you might consider periodically sending keep-alive messages at the largest granularity you can tolerate to ensure it will be reactivated at that interval and have a chance to act on a timeout (via timestamps stored in IndexedDB) that should have triggered while it slept.